# ASP.NET Website Administrator Tool in VS 2013

Tags: asp.net

Is there a short cut method to open website administrator in visual studio 2013, other than the method specified below

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Hi all, I was trying to search for this now for 2 weeks finally found something that could help. I am sharing this that can help someone. First Option: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24305/How-to-Add-the-Visual-Studio-Command-Prompt-VSCP-t Second Option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wdee4yb6.aspx Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how either of those help, since those are for the VSCP. You can accomplish the same thing with the regular command prompt. I suppose it might save you from clicking on a shortcut for the command prompt or something pinned to the taskbar, though. You still have to enter the command to run IISExpress, then open a browser and navigate to the proper URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long wait, here is the replacement for the ASP.NET Website Administrator Tool:

[**Thinktecture.IdentityManager as a replacement for the ASP.NET WebSite Administration tool**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx)

> Since then, ASP.NET has introduced ASP.NET Identity and community member Brock Allen created IdentityReboot with some significant improvements and extensions. Brock Allen and Dominick Baier have gone even further and created Thinktecture IdentityManager. It's the beginnings of a nice bootstrapped replacement for the missing ASP.NET Website Administration Tool. It is nicely factored and supports both ASP.NET Identity and their alternative called MembershipReboot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's cool, I ended up for the 100th time on that page, One thing: 
How do I start using it? I installed the nuget packages, now what? Is there a how-to-start guide? Where do I find the admin pages, I mean pages like WSAT?

Comment: Please follow the link... it shows all the steps :)

Comment: No they don't. Let's start with a very simple question: "Where do I find the admin pages, I mean pages like WSAT?" :)

Answer (score 8):

1. By **Windows Explorer**, copy folder **ASP.NETWebAdminFiles** and all its content to your solution folder (root folder of your WebApplications).

   > **ASP.NETWebAdminFiles** exists in **%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\**
   >
   > **%systemroot%** usually refers to **C:\Windows**
2. On **VS2013+ \ Solution Explorer Window**, do right click on your solution name; go over **Add**, on expanded menu click on **Existing Web Site...** item.
3. On opened dialog, on left pane choose **File System**, on right pane browse to your solution folder and select **ASP.NETWebAdminFiles** then click on **Open** button.
4. In added web site, in folder **App_Code**, find and open **WebAdminPage.cs** then:

   4.1. find class `WebAdminPage` , find method `OpenWebConfiguration`  that has 3 parameters, replace last line of code with this:

   ```
   return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(fileMap, path, "localhost");
   ```

   you can use `domain name` or `IP Address` instead of `localhost`

   4.2. find class `WebAdminModule`, find method `SetSessionVariables`, find first `if` block:

   ```
   if (application.Context.Request != null) { ... }
   ```

   inside `if` block, replace two lines of codes with these:

   ```
   queryStringAppPath = "/";
   queryStringApplicationPhysicalPath = @"D:\PHYSICAL\PATH\OF\YOUR\MAIN\WEB\APPLICATION\";
   ```

   4.3. Make sure provided physical path ends with a BACKSLASH.

   4.4. [**NEW**] if you going to run this tool on `localhost`, in class `WebAdminModule`, find method `OnEnter` then find first `if` block:

   ```
   if (!application.Context.Request.IsLocal) {...}
   ```

   make whole of block as commented text:

   ```
   //if (!application.Context.Request.IsLocal) {...}
   ```

   4.5. On **VS2013+ \ Solution Explorer Window**, click on `ASP.NETWebAdminFiles`, on **Properties Window** set **Windows Authentication** as **Enabled** then set **Anonymous Authentication** as **Disabled**.

   4.6. Set `ASP.NETWebAdminFiles` website as StartUp Project then run it.
5. It works, I use it for my applications over Intranet and web.

Good luck.

Comment: I get message fileMap does not exist the current context when i paste the code in step 4.1. Any advice on how to fix?

Comment: If you are using this App on web or intranet, replace **"localhost"** with true domain name or IP of application server.