# ASP Website Administration Tool : Unable to connect to SQL Server database(Security Tab)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need your help with ASP Website Administration Tool! I already tried this:

[Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool)

and this

[ASP.NET Website Administrator Tool in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798880/asp-net-website-administrator-tool-in-vs-2013?lq=1)

I also tried uninstalling SQL Server but nothing changed I still couldn't get into the Web Admin Tool!Well, actually I have but the moment I click the security tab it will say that it is Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

heres my web connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SecurityDB" connectionString="Data Source=Ryan;Initial Catalog=SecurityDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and the membership and the role

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" />
<membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add 
              name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
              connectionStringName="SecurityDB" 
              enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
              enablePasswordReset="true" 
              requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
              applicationName="/" 
              requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
              passwordFormat="Hashed" 
              maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
              minRequiredPasswordLength="9" 
              minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
              passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
              passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add 
        name="MyRoleProvider" 
        connectionStringName="SecurityDB" 
        applicationName="/" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

and btw I also tried using aspnet_regsql.exe hoping that it might help but unfortunately it didn't. I also checked the machine.config and i just copy pasted the role and membership block after that I change to the connectionStringName to the one I'm currently using(SecurityDB).

Comment: does the user account running the site have permission in that db?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's difficult to understand what is your question, and to which tool it relates. I believe you receive `Unable to connect to SQL Server database` in Web Admin Tool. Could you have a look and edit the title at least to better reflect what you are asking for.

Comment: how do i check if the user have the proper permission in the db?I also checked that but I don't know where to look :)

Answer (score 0):

The website administration tool is not in visual studio 2013. It is on the 2010 version though.

Comment: [this may help.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: Although I've not tested it.

Comment: Oh fair enough. There's something similar built into iis I think but I have never used it. Also not sure what it's called either, sorry not very helpful I know.